# vulkan synchronization between two command buffers with semaphores

Tags: synchronization, vulkan

I am trying to synchronize two command buffers with semaphores, but it doesn't work.

The code is like:

```
queueSubmit(imageAvailable, cmd1Finished, cmd1);
queueSubmit(cmd1Finished, renderFinished, cmd2);
```

Which the first parameter is the semaphore to wait, the second is the semaphore to signal, the third one is the command buffer.

With above, the resulting image is continually twinkling. Then I try this:

```
queueSubmit(imageAvailable, cmd1Finished, cmd1);
vkQueueWaitIdle(queue);
queueSubmit(cmd1Finished, renderFinished, cmd2);
```

Which works properly.Then I want to ask if I miss something to make it correct.

Comment: did you put the correct WaitStageMask in the submission?

Comment: Can you post more details? At the level of detail you provided you're doing the right thing, so it's either a bug in the details you've omitted, or it's a bug in the driver.

Comment: Also, can you explain why you're using semaphores on the same queue? It seems to me that an event would be more appropriate; you could then send the two CBs in the same batch.

Comment: The wait stage is VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT.

Comment: I never use a event before, since semaphores can do that, I want to know why it doesn't work.After that, I will try events.

Comment: I have tried events, they works!!

Comment: The wait stage is too late: you're saying to allow work in cmd2 to proceed, except that before the fragment shader output is written to the color attachments, wait for the semaphore to signal. Assuming you're sampling from the image in the fragment shader, you want to wait before launching fragment shader threads, so VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT.

Comment: VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT still doesn't work, even though the VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT.

Comment: The events, which wait for the VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, it is okey.